# Incrementing Counter in List - Int Objects not Iterable Error

Tags: python, list, integer, counter

I am looking to increment two separate counters contained in a list and I am having the error 'int objects not iterable' returned as an error. How can I increase the integer stored in the specified place?

```
dc_counter = 0

for i in range(15):
    for i in range(2):
        decision_counter[dc_counter].append([0])
    dc_counter += 1

line_counter = 0

for j in all_decisions:
    if all_decisions[line_counter][4] == 1:
        decision_counter[session_num][0] += 1

    elif all_decisions[line_counter][4] == 2:
        decision_counter[session_num][1] += 1

    line_counter +=1
```

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing traceback

Comment: Given the error message, I'd guess that in `for j in all_decisions:` your `all_decisions` is an integer.

Comment: @jonsharpe The error isn't coming from that line, it's coming from decision_counter[session_num][0]

Comment: please [edit] your question to include the *full* traceback of the error. don't feed us crumbs piecemeal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `decision_counter` is one layer of `list`s deeper than you expected. Sample:

```
[[[0], [1]], [[0], [1]], [[0], [1]], [[0], [1]]]
```

What you most likely intended was:

```
[[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
```

To do that, remove the brackets from the append:

```
decision_counter[dc_counter].append(0)    # <-- append(0) instead of append([0])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell just what you are trying to accomplish, but it looks like your code could be reduced to something like

```
SESSIONS = 15
decision_count = [[0]*2 for _ in range(SESSIONS)]

for session in range(SESSIONS):
    for dec in all_decisions:
        decision_counter[session][dec[4] - 1] += 1
```